# android apply audio pcm filter on output mix

Tags: android, audio, pcm

I got some PCM filter routines and hope apply on android output mix.
When any media player is playing a music, the audio performance could be enhanced.
Could anyone kindly to help me ? Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html)

Creating a Visualizer on the output mix (audio session 0) requires permission `MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS`
i dont know if you need `RECORD_AUDIO` permision as well

Here is a link to some working [source code](http://www.vogella.com/code/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/AudioFxDemo.html)

```
   // Create the Visualizer object and attach it to our media player.
                             // you want the audiosessionid here to be 0 for output mix
    mVisualizer = new Visualizer(0); 
    mVisualizer.setCaptureSize(Visualizer.getCaptureSizeRange()[1]);
    mVisualizer.setDataCaptureListener(new Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener() {
        public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes,
                int samplingRate) {
            mVisualizerView.updateVisualizer(bytes); // this is the where you put the pcm routine
        }

        public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer visualizer, byte[] bytes, int samplingRate) {}
    }, Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate() / 2, true, false);  
}
```